# What do percentages mean on a BF3 server description?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3, xbox-network

I am a bit behind the curve, and just started playing BF3. I played BFBC2, and liked it, and enjoy what I see so far in BF3.

The new server setup confuses me though. Since it appears that there are no more 'standard' servers (think BC2 or even most other games on the xbox like Halo or CoD), you can see a list of all of these 'public' shared servers, with odd descriptions.

One thing I noticed a lot through them was people saying '500% on [map name]'. I was very unsure of what this meant.

I was in an awesome match last night, and after dying once, I was kicked. I had no clue what for. Because I had just selected 'quick match' I was unsure of any server rules. I would like to understand what hosts are meaning by their description.

Comment: You were probably kicked for either (a) using a "banned" weapon, (b) to make room for a member of the clan running the server, or (c) because you killed an admin too many times and he got frustrated

Comment: There still are standard servers, but not many. Servers that are named PXXXXXX (where X is a number) are usually "EA-owned" and ones that have [DICE] in the name, are usually "DICE-owned". However, some people will often name their servers using these to get people to play on them. Just check the "owner" field before you join a game to see if it is a public- or private-run server

Comment: Doubt a banned weapon, only a level 1 with default loadouts. If anything, I guess I just looked like too much of a newbie or had to high of a death to kill ratio. Thanks for the help on public/private. I wish they would almost segregate them for those who want. I like the idea of the custom servers, but starting off I just want to get going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means 500% increase in tickets per round. It essentially makes the rounds last longer because there are more tickets. See this for more details on how tickets work: http://www.battlefield.com/uk/battlefield3/blog/battlefield-3-battleblog-11

Comment: So if one wants less of a 'growing' game, they should stay away from these with percentages.

Comment: @jmlumpkin I don't play a lot of multiplayer BF3 so I don't have any first hand experience with 500% games, although I don't really see the appeal of making the rounds last significantly longer. I see a lot of people complain about them taking too long.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I would actually want to stay away from these - I just didn't know what it meant.

Comment: I find that high ticket Team Death Match servers are really good for learning how to shoot and use cover.  It also helps to unlock attachments for your guns.  I do agree that high ticket conquest and rush games (in general) aren't very fun.

Comment: High ticket games sometimes are fun, and allow you to put up ridiculous numbers (i.e. I've nearly broken 200 kills in a Conquest round and over 100,000 XP in another), but they take forever (one game took 1h51m, and another that took ~80m froze my Xbox in the middle of the game and I had to restart it)

Answer (score 2):

The typical reason for such server settings is to provide an environment where players can gain XP as fast as possible. This is why you'll see a lot of Metro 64 player servers with high ticket counts - Metro being full of intense activity choke points where you can drop medkits or ammo packs and rack up points, or even just fire into the maw blindly and score kills.

If you actually want to improve your play, avoid these servers (unless you want to test unfamiliar loudouts quicky).